# Blister or infection?

Tags: dogs

My dog was neutered about 14 days ago. And the wound healed very well said my vet(about a week ago) and it seemed like it too. However, a couple days ago, right next to the surgical sight (not actually on it), a red blister type thing appeared. And today it's gotten a bit bigger. I've taken a picture and posted it on this post. Is this something to be worried about and needs immediate medical attention? Also, for the last week or so, we've been playing with him and taking him to the park. So could that have aggravated the issue?
[image]

Also, I don't know if this information will help, but when we was neutered, they patched him up with medical glue instead of stitches. He doesn't lick the wound nor pay it any attention. He doesn't seem to be in pain either in that area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> they patched him up with medical glue instead of stitches.

I would double check this as the more modern protocol for closing incision are internal absorbable sutures with an outer layer of medical glue.

> Also, for the last week or so, we've been playing with him and taking him to the park. So could that have aggravated the issue?

7-10 days is pretty sufficient for rest with dog castrations however we tend to say 14 to be extra safe. Dogs can get [seromas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seroma) post-surgery from too much exercise or rough housing.

> Is this something to be worried about and needs immediate medical attention?

I would visit your veterinarian (non-emergency) as typically they give you a free exam post-operation to make sure everything heals nicely. I personally believe it's a suture reaction to the knot of the suture pattern, we see this from time to time.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was internal absorbable sutures with glue on the outside. I just didn't know how to quite describe it. If it is a seroma or a suture reaction, what is the best way to deal with it? Can it possible heal with some good resting at home?

Comment: Seromas go away with time and rest - suture reactions can go away as well  however sometimes we need to take it out if possible. I would still get the complimentary exam as with a photo alone i cannot feel the surgical site for abnormal swelling or to extract discharge if any.